# Вопрос по-поводу $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, url

Товарищи! ☭

Если нам необходимо получить предыдущий (относительно текущего) url, то мы используем `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. А если нужно получить url до предыдущего? Допустим, текущий url у нас — `site.org/delitePost/2`, на него мы попали, скажем, с `site.org/post/2`, а на него с `site.org/listPosts`. Вопрос: как получить этот, последний? Решение необходимо именно на стороне сервера, т. е. только на php, исключая js.

Comment: Вот что говорит `php.net` о `HTTP_REFERER`

`Адрес страницы (если есть), с которой браузер пользователя перешёл на эту страницу. Этот заголовок устанавливается браузером пользователя. Не все браузеры устанавливают его, а некоторые в качестве дополнительной возможности позволяют изменять содержимое заголовка HTTP_REFERER.`
Одним словом, нельзя доверять этому заголовку.

Мне кажется если вам нужно делать систему "отслеживания" необходимо использовать... да хотябы COOKIE

Comment: @BigTows, да, я знаю, сам к нему с недоверием отношусь. Может быть возможно найти более надёжное решение этого вопроса на php? Какую-то функцию написать?

Comment: А для чего это вам? Насколько это должно быть достоверно?

Comment: @BigTows, вы таки будете смеяться, но я настолько слаб, что не могу прикрутить к своему велосипеду вывод flash-сообщений и в связи с этим, решил сделать то, на что (по-моему мнению) у меня хватит мозгов. При проверках форм, удалении/редактировании, сообщения выводятся на отдельной странице, после чего, надо вернуться в исходный контроллер. Только не кидайтесь помидорами :)

Comment: Если я правильно понял в момент удаления "поста" (это у нас `site.org/delitePost/2`) и вам нужно вернуться к `site.org/listPosts` или это не обязательно будет `site.org/listPosts`?

Comment: @BigTows, нет, совсем не обязательно. Допустим, при отправке сообщения админу, юзер ввёл ахинею в поле «email» и ему вылазит сообщение, после чего, его нужно вернуть обратно на /addMessage. А если админ удаляет сообщение (/deliteMessage/2), то, если его туда вернуть, он получит — /404, по этому его нужно вернуть на /listMessages. Но там есть не только сообщения, там есть страницы, статьи, файлы и пр. Вот :)

Comment: Ну я к тому что у вас есть "логичность", если это страница `message/2` то идем на `/listMessages`, если это `/delitePost/2` то идем на `/listPosts`

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл добавить логику в эти контроллеры.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112816/discussion-between-linne-and-bigtows).